# how to set spacing in gwt docklayout panel

Tags: gwt

in the old dockpanel, i can call the method setSpacing() to set the spacing between different child of the dockpanel, however the docklayoutpanel dont have htis method anymore, how can do set the spacing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UiBinder - and I recommend that you do - you can use CSS to set margins and padding on the child widgets. You can also use `someWidget.getElement().getStyle()` to manipulate CSS.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that child widgets get absolutely positioned with all sides set to 0 (top, bottom, left and right) make it a little bit tricky? I couldn't find the clean way to set margin/padding but  to wrap widget with **<g:FlowPanel>** in order for it comply with given CSS values...